# Is linear response only the first term in a series expansion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, non-linear-systems, multipole-expansion

So in the theory of linear response, the goal is to look at how certain dynamical variables (or operators in QFT) respond to an external source. To be more concrete, suppose that $x$ obeys (in index notation)

\begin{equation}
\dot{x_i} + g_i(x,t) = f_i(t)
\end{equation}

where $f_i$ would typically be called the source or the forcing term. Further, let's say the solution in the absence of forcing ($f(t) := 0$) is $x^{(0)}(t)$. In the regime of weak forcing ($f(t) \ll 1$) the deviation from $x^{(0)}(t)$ is governed by linear response

\begin{equation}
x_i(t) - x_i^{(0)}(t) = \int dt' \chi_{ij}(t-t')f_j(t') 
\end{equation}

where repeated indicies are summed over. In my experience, $\chi$ is called the response function. My question is whether this can be extended to larger source terms by including further terms. For example, I was imagining there would be a term at the next order

\begin{equation}
x_i(t) - x_i^{(0)}(t) = \int dt' \chi_{ij}(t-t')f_j(t') + \int dt' dt'' \alpha_{ijk}(t-t',t-t'')f_j(t')f_k(t'') + O(f^3)
\end{equation}

Where $\alpha$ is some second order response function that serves a similar purpose to $\chi$. This is certainly not linear anymore, so this is not linear response anymore. Is this correct? Has work been done on this, or is this an unpromising area to study? I am just finishing my undergrad, so my exposure to this stuff is fairly limited.

Comment: This is correct. In principle, $x$ will depend on all orders of $f$. The $n^{\text{th}}$ order correction to the response will involve a tensor of rank $n+1$. Linear response theory is simply the first order correction in a perturbative expansion.

Comment: Can't this be answered via the definition of linearity: L(x+y) = L(x) + L(y)?

Comment: For QFT, this is the $n$ point [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_(quantum_field_theory))